# How to double array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
arr = ["a", "b", c"]
```

I want to double values like

```
arr = ["a", "b", c", "a", "b", "c"]
```

(not in particular order).

What's the best way to do it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Possible solution, using `Array#concat`.

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"],
    res = arr.concat(arr);
    
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use [ES6 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) with `Array.push`:

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
arr.push(...arr);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Didn't work, froze the app

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array()` constructor and inside specify number of times you want to repeat array and then use `fill()` and spread syntax to create one array.

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

var newArr = [].concat(...Array(3).fill(arr))
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

A for-loop solution which mutates the array itself.

```js
var arr=["a","b","c"];
var len=arr.length;
for(var i=len;i<2*len;i++) arr[i]=arr[i-len]
console.log(arr);
```